# AssemblyFileVersionAttribute - Non Version Data Possible?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I know this may sound silly, but I'd like to put a version in my FileVersion (since it's not used for referencing, but to indicate what version the file is) that isn't in the standard `System.Version` Format of `major.minor.build.revision`.

To be frank, I'd like to put my repository changeset hash in there, because It accurately represents the version of the file. (I.e the dll generated from the given changeset).

Since the Attribute takes a string input (since `Version` isn't constant), **will I break anything by doing this?**

Would `AssemblyInformationVersionAttribute` be better suited for this task? Or is this just flat out going to cause me pain when something assumes it's a MS Formatted Version #?

Comment: Couldn't you use the revision part to hold your changeset hash?

Comment: @Philipp Schmid: Changeset Hashes are Hexadecimal, and long. `1.0.0.f516f300d51dd45fa83d99d64c70b5c7e97f6e6b` is not exactly a valid `System.Version`

Comment: In fact, Revision on the `System.Version` type is a `short` so it holds even less information than the other parts.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of TFS changeset numbers, which are numbers not hashes. What about a date/time value instead? Could you find the changeset that way (I don't know which source control system you are using).

Comment: I'm using Mercurial, and no date-time wouldn't be simple enough, and is prone to the system clock being different on different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exposing something that's available to *anybody*.  The unmanaged version resource that's generated from the attributes is easily accessible.  FileVersionInfo class in .NET.  Do note the FileMajor/MinorPart properties, they are integers, not strings.  So, yes, the odds that one of those *anybody* is going to fall over are slim but not zero.  [assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("blah")] doesn't help, that becomes the "Product version".

That doesn't leave anything but [AssemblyTitle].  A bit bewildering to your users but that's all.

Comment: Interestingly Enough it doesn't matter for two reasons. **[1]**: This assembly is not accessible by the public (It's the libs/core of an ASP website). Even so, the hash doesn't expose anything really without the repo. **[2]**: It seems `FileVersionInfo` fails gracefully. Putting a hash in the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` causes the `ProductVersion` to output the hash (since it's a string), and the individual int parts to report 0. Seems this is a non-issue. With that said, thanks for the input, you lead me to understanding the implications of doing this, etc. Thankyou :)